# How to repeat an observable 10 times and get result 10 times?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I want to get the result from an observable 10 times, doesn't matter if it is an error or success. Here is what I am trying

```
mPortalNetworkService.getApi()
            .login(mUsername, mPassword, mEmail)
            .repeat(10)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                println("Finally here -> SUB")
                println(it)
            }, {
                println("Finally here -> Error")
                it.printStackTrace()
            })
```

I am calling a rest api for logging (using Retrofit).The problem I am facing is that it only returns the result once. I want the result all the `10` times I am running this observable. How do I do that?

Comment: remove and subscribe the observer simultaneously 10 times !!

Comment: @SantanuSur I am all the calls to execute in a sequence.

Comment: Does that mean, you want to execute one request after another or all at the same time?

Comment: @HansWurst, Yes, I want one request after the other.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no operator that would combine `repeat` and `retry` behavior for you. You can either setup a `range`-based solution suggested by Hans or you can share a counter between `repeat` and `retry` to limit both:

```java
static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> redo(int maxCount) {
    return o -> {
        Observable.defer(() -> {
            AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(maxCount);
            return o.repeat(() -> count.incrementAndGet() < maxCount)
                    .retry(err -> count.incrementAndGet() < maxCount);
        });
    };
}

mPortalNetworkService.getApi()
        .login(mUsername, mPassword, mEmail)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .compose(redo(10))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            println("Finally here -> SUB")
            println(it)
        }, {
            println("Finally here -> Error")
            it.printStackTrace()
        })
```

Note that to make sure `login` happens on a background thread, you have to `subscribeOn` before repeating/retrying.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create 10 requests you could just use #range in order to generate 10 values and map each value to a new request. Every request will be flatmapped with maxConcurrency = 1. You could also use concatMap in order to make a request after the request before finishes.

```
  @Test
  public void name() {
    Api api = mock(Api.class);
    when(api.login()).thenReturn(Flowable.just(42));
    TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

    Flowable<Result> resultFlowable =
        Flowable.range(0, 10)
            .flatMap(
                __ -> {
                  Flowable<Result> resultObservable =
                      api.login()
                          .map(integer -> Result.ok())
                          .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
                          .onErrorReturn(throwable -> Result.fail());

                  return resultObservable;
                },
                1);

    TestSubscriber<Result> test = resultFlowable.test();
    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);

    test.assertValueCount(10) //
        .assertNoErrors()
        .assertComplete();
  }

  interface Api {
    Flowable<Integer> login();
  }

  static class Result {
    private Result() {}

    static Result ok() {
      return new Result();
    }

    static Result fail() {
      return new Result();
    }
  }
```